# Using Python, how to add an item to the right-click context menu in Windows Explorer?

Tags: python, windows, registry

I've been looking around, and found the `_winreg` module, but that seems like a risky method (fooling around with the registry, that is). Is there any other way?

I've skimmed this so far: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx and it looks like I'd need to add a key here: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<File Type>\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`.

I just want to play it safe before I actually make any changes.

Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833710/windows-explorer-context-menus-with-sub-menus-using-pywin32

Comment: @jsalonen Thanks, that looks like it'd work well. Doesn't seem as simple as I had initially hoped!

Comment: Yeah, I know. But at least you CAN do that!