# How to access 64-bit registry from a 32-bit process?

Tags: c++, registry, x86-64, win64, wow64

I have a program that integrates with explorer context menu. It works properly in Win32 but not in Win64. I've compiled the shell extension to Win64 but now I want to register that

The DLL file from the main program is 32 bit and I also want to keep the main program as 32 bit.

I want to access the CLSID key under in `Wow6432Node` under `HKEY_CLASS_ROOT`. I used `RegDisableRef` but it doesn't work

Comment: So your question is actually "How do I register a 64-bit shell extension from a 32-bit application?", if I understand you. Is that correct? (There's a lot of clutter there.)

Comment: you said that the shell extension has been compiled to 64-bit but now why the DLL file is 32-bit? It'd be easier to have the whole program in the same bitness, since you only need to recompile the source code without worrying about the 64-32 cross process intercommunication

Comment: This is the first x86 / x86-64 question I've seen that's *actually* talking about the Windows registry, not asm registers like RAX.  And that's a lot of question over the years to get gold badges in them; many dozens of questions with that mistake.  (Apparently a lot of non-native speakers mistranslate and write write "registry" in questions about CPU registers).  After seeing the question title, I literally clicked on this expecting to click edit and change it to registers.  :P  Turns out, not an assembly-language question at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just like how [files are redirected by WoW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector), registry accesses are also redirected

> The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by providing separate logical views of certain portions of the registry on WOW64. The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit and 64-bit registry calls to their respective logical registry views and maps them to the corresponding physical registry location. The redirection process is transparent to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit Windows.
>
> [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/registry-redirector)

You need to specify `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` on the `samDesired` parameter when accessing 64-bit registry keys with `RegCreateKeyEx`, `RegDeleteKeyEx` or `RegOpenKeyEx`

> The following flags enable 32-bit applications to access redirected keys in the 64-bit registry view and 64-bit applications to access redirected keys in the 32-bit registry view. These flags have no effect on shared registry keys. For more information, see [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).
>
> | Flag name | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | KEY_WOW64_64KEY | 0x0100 | Access a 64-bit key from either a 32-bit or 64-bit application. |
> | KEY_WOW64_32KEY | 0x0200 | Access a 32-bit key from either a 32-bit or 64-bit application. **Windows 10 on ARM**: This refers to the 32-bit ARM registry view for 32-bit ARM processes and the 32-bit x86 registry view for 32-bit x86 and 64-bit ARM64 processes. |
>
> [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view)

However I think compiling the program in separate 32 and 64-bit versions will be easier. Most programs don't need to change when recompile. Moreover you'll still have to recompile the shell extension because [64-bit processes can't load 32-bit DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13747836/995714)