# How to gray out some context-menu options with an IExecuteCommand-based shell extension?

Tags: c++, windows, shell, winapi, contextmenu

When implementing a context-menu shell extension using the `IExecuteCommand` approach (as described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/12/9977246.aspx)), how can a given menu option be grayed out?

E.g. Suppose that the shell extension offers some menu options, and some of them should be grayed out basing on some state and conditions that the shell extension computes, for example: if the user right-clicks on a file and the shell extension detects that this file has some given properties, some of the shell extension context menu options should be grayed out.

How to do that using `IExecuteCommand`?

Or should another Windows Shell COM interface be used for that purpose?

Comment: Not sure about `IExecuteCommand` but [`IContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used. The [InsertMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function allows you to set information about the item including ['MFS_DISABLED'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which disables the menu item and grays it so that it cannot be selected.

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible with `IContextMenu`, thanks. (In fact, before the introduction of `IExecuteCommand` in Windows 7, I wrote shell extensions using the "good old" `IContextMenu`). I was just curious if this would be possible also with `IExecuteCommand`, or if this new COM interface for context-menu shell extensions is such limited to not allow something as basic as this feature. (In that case, frankly speaking I would define `IExecuteCommand` mostly useless...). But I'm not sure about that, so I thought of asking here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this but you should be able to set `CommandState­Handler` (undocumented?) in your verb's key to a CLSID that implements [IExplorerCommandState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378380(v=vs.85).aspx).

You might also think about implementing [IExplorerCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761880(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of IExecuteCommand+IExplorerCommandState...

You can also hide verbs based on a query to the property system with the `AppliesTo` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that I've upvoted. I didn't know about the COM interfaces you cited, thanks for sharing this information. But at this point I wonder if it's just simpler to follow the _"classical"_ `IContextMenu` path... :)

Comment: Depends on which versions of Windows you need to support I guess, if it is Win7+ then these are less work and more to the point.

Comment: **`CommandStateHandler`** is documented here in [Guidance for Implementing In-Process Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx): _"`IExplorerCommandState` associated with a **`CommandStateHandler`** entry registered under a **shell** \verb subkey."_. Thanks for pointing this interface out!