# Python - Add item to the file right click context menu

Tags: python, windows, shell, contextmenu, right-click

I want to create an application that will **add a preprogrammed function in windows context menu** when you **right click an file**.

I've been searching this for quite a time but not successfully.

For example, how to add the "add to archive" as winrar did:

[image: Windows context menu]

Or as the following "add 'open folder as project'" in pycharm's installation:

[image: Windows context menu]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833710/windows-explorer-context-menus-with-sub-menus-using-pywin32 Looks like this might be what you're asking for

Comment: I don't understand your question. Firstly, what do you mean you want _to do_ a program? Secondly, what does it mean to _add an item to the file right click context menu_ ? Can you please elaborate? Also, please include what you've tried so far and what your _expected output_ is.

Comment: do you mean context menu in standard file manage, excel, other program or in own program ?

Comment: as I remeber in system's register you could add field `"open"` to field `".py"` with path to program used to open file with extension `".py"`. But it needed manual work with register. And it was long time ago. Now I don't use Windows.